# smtp error: 535 5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted for gmail in go

Tags: email, go, gmail

I'm trying to test an app's outgoing emails from localhost using this function:

```
func SendContactUsForm(subject, email, body string) error {
    var err error
    from := "mysender@gmail.com"
    pass := "somecrazypw"
    to := "mydestination@gmail.com"
    msg := "From: " + from + "\n" +
    "To: " + to + "\n" +
    "Subject: Contact form:" + subject + "\n" + body
    err = smtp.SendMail("smtp.gmail.com:587",
        smtp.PlainAuth("", from, pass, "smtp.gmail.com"),
        from, []string{to}, []byte(msg))
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("smtp error: %s", err)
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

But I get this error:

> send_emails.go:171: smtp error: 535 5.7.8 Username and Password not
>   accepted. Learn more at
>   5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials a7sm5381413wmh.14 - gsmtp contact.go:38: error seding contact us form
>   535 5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.

Despite the fact that the credentials of `mysender@gmail.com` are correct and I have enabled `Allow less secure apps` on `mysender@gmail.com`.

So what could be wrong here? And how can I fix it?

Comment: You reposted the same question and deleted the older one. So why post the same question, again? In fact, it was answered as well.

Comment: use Xoauth2 https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol

Comment: @DaImTo do you imply that it is not possible anymore to use user/password in order access to gmail from apps?

Comment: Username and Password not accepted. <-- does imply to me that Google is no longer accepting login and password on their smtp server.  your probably the tenth person to ask this in a different language in the past month.   Also if the user has 2fa enabled it wont work either.

Comment: If its a brand new gmail account that you just created it might not work immediately. This is what happened to me and instead I set up temporarily my normal gmail account and it worked : )

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Generate a password from https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords and use that password instead.

> An App Password is a 16-digit passcode that gives an app or device restricted access to your Google Account without having to divulge your personal password and complete access to your Google Account.

More [details](https://devanswers.co/create-application-specific-password-gmail/) on how to generate one!

Comment: It says: `The setting you are looking for is not available for your account.`

Comment: Enable the 2FA (2 Step Verification) authentication: https://myaccount.google.com/security

Comment: I enabled 2FA. Generated  16 character password and used it instead of my original `somecrazypw`. However I still get the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha (Enable it to let your app access your account)

Comment: Just realized that `from` email should be the same as `mysender@gmail.com` user/passwd, otherwise google does not deliver it and gives error.  So  `noreply@myapp.com` is not allowed. Thanks for your tips.

Answer (score 11):

2023: Allowing less secure apps is not permitted.
Solution: Login to your gmail account, go to Account Settings> Privacy and enable 2FA.
After this search for App Passwords and create one, copy this and enter it as the password for your app.
This shall solve any authentication errors, you are facing.

Comment: +Rep for the year inclusion in answer. Worked well. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

If you have enabled 2-factor authentication on your Google account then you can't use your regular password to access mail through code. You need to generate an app-specific password and use that instead your actual password.

Do the following steps to generate app specific password,

- Log in to your Google account or use this link https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords
- Go to `My Account > Sign-in & Security > App Passwords`
- Scroll down to Select App in the Password & sign-in methds and choose Other (custom name) Give this app password a name, Eg: "automailer"
- Choose Generate Copy the long generated password and paste it into your script instead of your actual Gmail password.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Go to Security inside your gmail account and enable 3party APP access... This will fix the problem. FYI, I believe this wont work if you have 2-step auth turned on. So you may have to create a new gmail account and then enable forwarding....

Answer (score 1):

login to gmail account.
go to Manage your google account.
turn ON Less secure app access
after this when you try to send mail from your app you might get error .
if so go to Security issues found ( it's first option in security tab of google account )
here you need to verify that last activities is verified and its you .

Comment: This setting is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

1-turn on 2-step verification in your google acount => security

2-in the {Signing in to Google } then go to App passwords  and set a password for your app(for example for PHPMailer).then put this password in your sendmail file in your project.

Comment: what should i do if i want to avoid to turning on the  2-step verification

Answer (score 0):

Just Enable the 2 step verification on then and then only you are able to generate "App Password" for any Gmail account.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting user error smtp error: 535 5.7.8, not letting me verify the email. It took me hours trying all the steps above to no avail. Finally, I could
add another Gmail address to my main Gmail account.

Open Gmail - click on the setting icon wheel upper right corner
Click See All Settings
Click Account
Under Send Email click Add Another Email Address
Enter the name you want to be shown when someone opens the email
Enter the email address you are sending from or an alias address
...Next step is where the verification and error message happens
Instead of adding your new or alias address and password, add your main G-Mail account username and password.

Good Luck!