# Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted when trying to send email from nodemailer

Tags: node.js, smtp, gmail

Cannot send an email from node-mailer on the VPS. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188483/error-invalid-login-535-5-7-8-username-and-password-not-accepted) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62302054/smtp-error-535-5-7-8-username-and-password-not-accepted-for-gmail-in-go) too, but the accepted solution for some reason does not work for me. Any ideas on how to fix it?

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: "c***n@gmail.com",
        pass: "****************",
    },
});

const info = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: '"CloudFave" <c***n@gmail.com>', // sender address
    to: "someone@gmail.com", // list of receivers
    subject: "Hello", // Subject line
    text: "Hello world?", // plain text body
    html: "<b>Hello world?</b>", // html body
});

console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
```

Comment: Please include your code in your post as text without any of your credentials.